# Not able to access public variable in derived class

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a variable with a specified font, but the string is null so nothing is visible in the output. please go through the code and help me to find the error

```
 class BasicClass
{
    public string str;
    public Font fnt;
}
class BasicMethod:BasicClass
{
    public void changevalues(string newstr,Font newfnt)
    {
        str = newstr;
        fnt = newfnt;
    }
}
class PrintClass:BasicClass
{
    public void print()
    {

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        PaperSize psize = new PaperSize();
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pd.Document = pdoc;
        pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);

        DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            ppd.Document = pdoc;
            ppd.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.5;
            ((Form)ppd).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            DialogResult ppdResult = ppd.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
    void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        //string str1 = "XYZ";
        //Font fnt1 = new Font("Arial", 12.5f);            
        g.DrawString(str, fnt, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10);

    }

}
```

Button Click event

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BasicMethod bm = new BasicMethod();
        PrintClass pc = new PrintClass();
        Font ft = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12.5f);
        bm.changevalues("Hello", ft);
        pc.print();

    }
```

i need to get the output `Hello`

Comment: Congrats on finding the answer! You should go to your previous question and add an answer linking to the answer on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the values you want in a completely different object from the one where you try to use them.

One way to fix this:

Change the `PrintClass` so that it inherits the `BasicMethod` class instead of `BasicClass`

```
class PrintClass : BasicMethod
```

Then change your click handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintClass pc = new PrintClass();
    Font ft = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12.5f);
    pc.changevalues("Hello", ft);
    pc.print();
}
```